# Emacs: Default Windows

Tags: display, emacs

Is there a way to configure Emacs to start with two windows automatically, vertically split, and with the right side taking up ~60% of the total screen real estate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a way I bet you can find it on this page: [Emacs Session Management](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement)

Comment: Great! It looks like this will do: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WorkgroupsForWindows

Comment: (-1) that doesn't really answer the question

Comment: I agree with David., Its better to write answer here on this page instead of linking to some where else.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you start with a window that is 80 columns by 50 columns, add this to your .emacs (from [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Splitting-Windows.html)):

- To start with Horizontal split:

  ```
  (setq w (selected-window))
  (window-edges)
  (setq w2 (split-window w 15))
  (window-edges w2)
  (window-edges w)
  ```
- To start with Vertical split (to get 60% on the right side, the width is set to `40 * (1 - 0.6) = 32`

  ```
   (setq w (selected-window))
   (window-edges)
   (setq w2 (split-window w 32 t))
   (window-edges w2)
   (window-edges w)
  ```

Comment: this really answer the question. even though I would rather put all in  a `lambda` and add it to `init-hook`

Comment: @kindahero it does answer the original question, but only by copy and paste with minor modification. A better answer would explain what you mean by lambda and init-hook as well as what the code means and how it could be adapted (e.g. to open four windows instead of two).